# SQL Agent embedded PowerShell script in CmdExec step fails with import-module sqlps

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent, powershell

SQL Server 2008R2
PowerShell 2.1

I am trying to create a SQL Agent job that dynamically backs up all non-corrupted SSAS databases on an instance without the use of SSIS. In my SQL Agent job, when I create a CmdExec step and point to a PowerShell script file (.ps1) like this:

```
powershell.exe "c:\MyPSFile.ps1"
```

the job executes successfully (or at least gets far enough to only encounter logic or other syntax issues).

This approach won't work for a final solution, because there is a requirement to keep the PowerShell script internal to SQL. So I have a different CmdExec step that embeds the PowerShell script like so:

```
powershell.exe "import-module sqlps –DisableNameChecking

$server_name = "localhost"
$backup_location = "C:\BackupsGoHere"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.AnalysisServices") | out-null
$server = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server
$server.connect($server_name)

# Generate an array of databases to be backed up
foreach ($database in ($server.get_Databases() | Where {$_.EstimatedSize -gt 0 -and $_.Cubes.Count -gt 0})) {
    $directory_path = $backup_location + "\" + $database.Name
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $directory_path)) {
        New-Item $directory_path -type directory | out-null
    }
    [string] $timestamp = date
    $timestamp = $timestamp.Replace(':','').Replace('/','-').Replace(' ','-')
    $database.Backup("$directory_path\$database-$timestamp.abf")
}
$server.disconnect()"
```

However, when executed with the embedded script, the job errors out quickly with the following response:

> The specified module 'sqlps' was not loaded because no valid module
>   file was found in any module directory.

Why can't I reference the module from an embedded script, but doing so in a ps1 file works just fine?

Comment: My first guess is that somehow the context of running the PowerShell.exe with an embedded script is different than the context of when it's run from a ps1 file. I'm not sure how to confirm that or resolve it though. Is it possible to use a full path to refer to the sqlps module?

Comment: Why do you need to add the layers of Agent to do this? Can't you just schedule the PowerShell script in Windows?

Comment: It's a customer-defined requirement to keep this all contained within SQL. That's why I can't even store the ps1 script for the CmdExec step to reference.

Comment: I tried escaping the double quotes in the script. Same error.

Comment: On my server (SQL2008 R2) I only get the sql provider by starting Powershell in SSMS.  Opening a PS console and typing $env:psmodulepath shows where it will look for modules but sqlps isn't in either C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\ or C:\users\Bruce\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\.  You might want to try modifying the $env:psmodulepath to add the path to the sqlps module, something like X:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008 R2 you can simply create your SQL Agent Job with the step configured as a "PowerShell" type, instead of trying to use the CmdExec. You only need to include the "meat" of your script. Since you are using the PowerShell type of a SQL Agent step it has already called the powershell.exe and imported the SQLPS module for you. So an example:
[image]

With your code I believe you can simply configure the step as shown below:
[image]

Comment: When I tried this last, I got errors because the SQL PowerShell step couldn't process some of the commands. I think, though, that I was working w/ a more robust script. Maybe this type of step will work now that the script has been stripped down. It's worth a try.